# Chaining promise results in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I have two functions which return a `Promise`. The first one returns a list of values that I want to iterate through and make a second call on each, accumulating to the result to send back.

```
function firstCall() {
 return new Promise(returns list of items);
}

function secondCall(someVal) {
  return new Promise(return single value);
}

function doSomething() {
  firstCall().then((response1) => {
    response1.someResult.map((item) => {
      secondCall(item).then((response2) => {
        //how to collect all?
      });
   });
  });
}
```

Any suggestion on how I can chain these Promise returning call and returning list of final result?

Comment: Which platform? Some engines have support for that - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: one thing you need to understand with the arrow function ... if you have a block of code (within {}) you need to explicitly return something, otherwise the return value will be `undefined` - if the body of the arrow function does not have `{}`, i.e. it's a single statement (sort of), the return is implied and not required (indeed, invalid to have a return in this case)

Comment: `.all` is how to do it.  You actually push each promise into an array then do the `.all` on the array of promises.  When `.all` is resolved, `.then` move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming that you are using ES6 or some polyfill (Bluebird, etc.) If that isn't the case, please update your question. If so, you can send an array of Promises to `Promise.all()` and get an array of answers back.

```js
function firstCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
  })
}

function secondCall(n) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(n * n);
  })
}

function doSomething() {
  firstCall()
    .then(response1 => {
      console.log(response1);
      let promises = response1.map(r => secondCall(r));

      Promise.all(promises)
        .then(response2 => {
          console.log(response2);
        })
    })
}

doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain promises just by passing the function that will take the results:

```
function firstCall() {
  return Promise.resolve([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
};

function secondCall(array) {
  return Promise.all(array.map(square)).then(results => { return results });
}

function square(n){
  return Promise.resolve(n*n);
}

function logger(results){
  console.log(results);
}

function doSomething() {
  return firstCall().then(secondCall).then(logger);
  // you can also chain a .catch() that will bubble up from any chained promise
}

doSomething(); // return value: Promise { <pending> }, logged elements: [ 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36 ]
```